# NoSQL database with insert-select-like support

Tags: database, nosql

I need to keep a schedule for things. Each schedule has a starting and ending time and cannot overlap with another schedule for the same thing. There will be many things, with roughly similar schedules. There will be easily dozens, if not hundreds times more reads then writes, so Im ok with writing to a master and reading from replicas. So, I need a database that supports atomic validation upon insertion against other existing records and has straightforward replication. Basically I would like to implement something like

```
insert into events
select 'my-event', 15, 18
where (select id from events where end < 15 limit 1) = (select id 
from events where start < 18 limit 1);
```

where my-event is an id, 15 is epoch start time and 18 is epoch end time in a NoSQL DB.

I have spent quite a bit of time googling different databases today, and so far I can see that Mongo supports validation, but it seems more or less a replacement for schema and Couchbase seems to have very SQL-like query language, but from docs its not clear if its only superficial. Does such a database exist?

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that you are trying to push an application logic to the database. I never heard of any database which has this validation internally (maybe triggers in a relational database?)

Couchbase is really good at fast/reads and writes at scale, and the query language makes it really good to query JSON. However, your application will need to validate if you have any clashes.